# Caret change background color with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I would like to change the background color of the caret(only) in a textarea or div on an html page. I would like it to like to be able to change it from a flashing semi-transparent yellow box to a semi-trasparent red box, set with javascript( or js lib), based on condition. Is this possible? I am not sure if this is possible in text area, but maybe there is a way to do it with transpanet textarea with div in background?

Answer (score 2):

I have created an example [here](https://codepen.io/rayanvga/pen/KEyrNE) that might help.

If you want to do it on condition, just add the class "example1" dynamically to the desired element.

```
if(condition)
{
      $('myElement').addClass('example1');
}
```